# Slanted text in newtxmath

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath, newtx

The `\textsl` and `\textit` appears to be same when I load the newtxmath,newtxtext package. Can anyone say why the error? My commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[scaled=1.12]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmbraces,varbb,scaled=1.12]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{CMlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{CMlargesymbols}{"01}


\newenvironment{que}[1][Problem.]{\begin{leftbar}\begin{trivlist}\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}\end{leftbar}}


\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{que}
Are there infinitely many pairs of positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $m\mid (n^{2}+1)$ and $n\mid (m^{2}+1)$?
\end{que}
\hfill \textsl{British Math Olympiad, Round 2, 2013}


\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

and the output looks like[image]

This is definitely not slanted text. Kindly help.

Screenshot when this worked fine

[image]

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  Similarly, for inline code, you can surround the text with `\``.

Comment: @JP-Ellis Thanks. I didn't know. Will keep this in mind :)

Comment: The `newtx` packages don't seem to provide a slanted-roman type face. As a fallback, `\textsl` and `\slshape` are interpreted as `\textit` and `\itshape`, respectively.

Comment: @Mico But it was perfectly working when I used couple of weeks ago. I will search and show you a screen shot soon

Comment: @Mico Added is the screenshot when \textsl was working well :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile the example with TeX Live 2013, I get slanted type; with TeX Live 2014 (freezed after 2015-02-01) there's no slanted type any more.

The reason is that the NewTX distribution underwent a major change on February 1, 2015.

Here's the relevant part of the `README` file.

> Changes in version 1.4
>   1. All text fonts are now based on TeXGyre Termes, and some modifications thereof. In T1 encoding, no composite glyphs are needed.

The TeX Gyre Termes fonts have no slanted shape either, as this excerpt of `t1qtm.fd` shows

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qtm}{b}{sl}{<->sub * qtm/b/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qtm}{m}{sl}{<->sub * qtm/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qtm}{b}{scsl}{<->sub * qtm/b/scit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{qtm}{m}{scsl}{<->sub * qtm/m/scit}{}
```

If you want to use the fonts provided by `mathptmx` for slanted, you can, although I don't recommend it, because the glyph coverage may be different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\makeatletter
% load the main fd file
\input{t1ntxtlf.fd}
% fix it using the legacy ptm family
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{m}{sl}{<-> \ntx@scaled ptmro8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{b}{sl}{<-> \ntx@scaled ptmbo8t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{bx}{sl}{<-> ssub * ntxtlf/b/sl}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc \textsl{abc}

\bfseries abc \textsl{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @S.C. Ask Michael Sharpe; typically, slanted variants are realized with a `SlantFont` instruction at the PostScript level, so it's just a matter to create suitable tfm and vf files (which can be automated).

Comment: @S.C. About reverting: there are historical archives, but it would be a hard job nonetheless. About mathptmx: not *so* difficult, but it hasn't the same glyph support..

Comment: @S.C. Added. I decline any responsibility. `;-)`

Comment: I decided to have some fun with this input file. How did you know which fd file you had to input? For example take the "Alegreya" font. It has so many files. If I want to make my italic as Alegreya then which fd file shud i input. For example there is this : http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/alegreya/latex/OT1Alegreya-LF.fd which i added and gave the command \DeclareFontShape but it just doesn't work :(

Comment: @S.C. You're walking in a mine field. `;-)`

Comment: I dont get you. Like anything wrong with my question?

Comment: @S.C. If the font has an accompanying font, like Alegreya, just prepare a minimal document; in the `.log` file you will recognize the relevant `.fd` file. Then you have to learn as much of NFSS internals as needed for doing the appropriate changes. Read `texdoc fntguide`.

Comment: You have taught me a lot. Went looked at the vf files and lo it worked :D. Thanks a ton. even this command from the txfonts for getting the slanted text in newtx works : \DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{m}{sl}{<-> s*[1.12] t1xsl}{}