# Slanted numbers in running header using Times

Tags: formatting

How do I get slanted numbers in the running page header when using Times? For CM they are slanted. TIA.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peraphs your question is connected with this old question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306955/slanted-text-in-newtxmath

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582703/numerals-in-headings-not-slanted-using-newtxtext where a hack and a workaround is provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is changing the font to another Times variant an option? If so, I have a couple of alternatives for you.

### Caveat

Thanks to campa's excellent comments, I have learned that tgtermes uses *italics* for the header, not a *slanted* variant (since there apparently is none).

If that doesn't bother you, have a look at the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Loading tgtermes and newtxmath (in that order!) 
% works by inserting italics instead of slanted text
% \usepackage{tgtermes}
% \usepackage{newtxmath}

% txfonts also works
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Some text

\[E=mc^2\]

\end{document}
```

[image: txfonts and tgtermes]

Comment: Sorry, I have in part misunderstood the answer: you meant loading `tgtermes` and `newtxmath` together, right? But the problem is the same: `tgtermes `has no slanted font, so it is replacing it with the _italic_ one. Look at the log, you'll find the corresponding warning. So yes, it seems to work, but one might question whether this is good. I'd rather patch the `book` class to use italic text in headings. But that might be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @campa, yes, you are right, of course! So loading `txfonts` would be the only preferred package?

Comment: Also, if you want to use `tgterms` and `newtxmath` you should load `tgtermes` first. Look at the numbers in math mode otherwise.

Comment: `txfonts` is a possibility, or the old `mathptmx`. Or you can cheat: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248981/82917

Comment: @campa, excellent, thank you! I will edit my answer to make it transparent that some font choices will replace the slanted font with true italics.